# If a domain ranks for one keyword, does Google prefer to rank it for similar keywords as well?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, pagerank, ranking

Say there's a website `example.com`

If the page `example.com/english-action-movies` ranks as number 1-10 on google search, is it likely that a new page created later `example.com/french-action-movies` will also rank well?

Does Google see that this domain ranked well for `<language>-action-movies`
and therefore prefer this domain for other `<languages>`?

---

In the example above I have used `language` as a way of a similar page, but this can be thought of as `hair-salons-in-new-york` vs `post-offices-in-new-york`.

Comment: Search engines are not people, they are machines. This means that there is no preference for anything. Instead, what is done, is that any page or site can only perform in search for what is found. Semantics can make some assumptions, however, using your example, performing well for one page does not advantage another that does not perform well or does not exist. Search performance is on a page by page basis.

Answer (score 1):

Every page in your site will rank differently based on the numerous parameters that Google use to index pages.

But still if your site has good domain authority, its juice gets passed to its other pages as well.

The best benefits will be gained if your **new pages are linked to already indexed/ranking pages**. + add them to your sitemap as well.

As in :

If page `www.example.com/directory1/page1` is already ranking good,then
The ideal strategy should be to have a new page `www.example.com/directory1/page2` linked from this page 1 or overall domain 
`www.example.com`(through footer or any widget) to increase this page's authority and indicate that to crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Your English movie URL has nothing to do with your French movie URL, the only common thing is that they have the same domain and if your domain is strong, your French movies will also show up on the first page of search engines.